# Should we have a tag for "good" or extend the "evil" tag to "good-and-evil"? (or have all three?)

Tags: discussion, tags

On one or more of my recent questions I would've use a tag like "good" but it doesn't exist. There is a tag [evil](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evil) however. Now that I have enough rep to create [good](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/good) I wonder if that's the best move or if most questions dealing with the subject of evil should be considered questions dealing with good vs. evil. If so we could expand [evil](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evil) to [good-and-evil](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/good-and-evil) or suchlike.

Opinions?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this one up. Let's let this one sit in meta for a couple days and see how people feel about it. There could be subtitles either way.

Answer (score 6):

I like the idea of expanding that tag to be [good-and-evil](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/good-and-evil) since the subjects are hard to talk about without some sort of contrast. If in the future we find a need to split them up we can but right now I don't see questions that are better off for only having one or the other.

Comment: Silence is a sign of agreement -- no one opposed, so I went ahead and suggested this. It'll take a while for the vote to pass, I reckon.